# Improved upper bound for second moment of reduced residues modulo $q$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

The question asked here is a follow up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358982/on-the-distribution-of-reduced-residues-by-montgomery-and-vaughan-missing-ca), which was answered by user GH from MO. [EDIT: The question is edited for clarification after receiving a comment on the original posting.]

As there, let $q$ be a natural number, let $P = \phi(q)/q$ be the "probability" that a randomly chosen integer is relatively prime to q. Then, following Montgomery and Vaughan in [On the distribution of reduced residues](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971274?seq=1), 
 the second moment of the number of reduced residues modulo $q$ in an
interval of length $h$ about its mean, $hP$, can be stated as
$$
M_2(q;h) = 
qP^2
\sum_{\substack{{r \mid q }\\{r > 1}}} 
\mu(r)^2
\left(
\prod_{\substack{ {p \mid q }\\{p \nmid r} }}
\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}
\right)
r^2 \phi(r)^{-2} \left\{ \frac{h}{r}\right\}\left( 1 - \left\{ \frac{h}{r}\right\}\right). 
$$
Applying the inequality $\{\alpha\}(1 - \{\alpha\}) \leq \alpha$ then gives the upper bound
$$\tag{1}
M_2(q;h)\leq qhP,
$$
while a lower bound is given by 
$$
M_2(q; h) \geq qhP - qhPQ + O(qhP^2)
$$
where $Q=\prod_{\substack{{p \mid q}\\{p>h}}} (1-1/p)$.

Since $\{\alpha\}\leq 1$, we also have that $\{\alpha\}(1 - \{\alpha\}) \leq 0.25$. This allows for a second upper bound,
$$\tag{2}
M_2(q;h) \leq 0.25 \, 
qP^2
\sum_{\substack{{r \mid q }\\{r > 1}}} 
\mu(r)^2
\left(
\prod_{\substack{ {p \mid q }\\{p \nmid r} }}
\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}
\right)
r^2 \phi(r)^{-2}. 
$$

As pointed out by user Ofir Gorodetsky in the comment below, the upper bound in (1) is already optimal for those choices of $q$ such that the upper and lower bounds are of same order. For example, taking $q=\prod_{p\leq h^C} p$ for large enough $C$, we have that $M_2(q;h)\asymp qhP$.

Here I'd like to consider the rather opposite situation, when $C$ is small. Specifically, take $q=\prod_{p\leq h^C} p$, where $C<1$. Then we have that $Q=1$ and the lower bound takes the form
$$
M_2(q; h) \geq O(qhP^2),
$$
which leaves some more wiggle room between the upper and lower bounds, and I'd like to know whether the upper bound in (2) this case provides some improvement on (1).

## Question

> Given $q=\prod_{p\leq h^C} p$, where $C<1$. Does the upper bound for $M_2(q;h)$ stated in (2) provide a sharper bound compared to (1) in this case? And is it possible to express the upper bound in (2) a bit more simplified or asymptotically?

Comment: At least for some families of $q$, the upper bound is already optimal in the sense that there is a matching lower bound of the same order magnitude; this follows from the general lower bound given at the end of your linked question. To be concrete, taking $q = \prod_{p \le h^C} p$ for sufficiently large $C$, we have $M_2(q;h) \asymp  qhP$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to an important clarification! I've edited the question to focus on the case when $q=\prod_{p\leq h^C} p$ and $C<1$, as in this case the lower bound should be $M_2(q;h)\geq O(qhP^2)$ (is it a better or more correct way to write this inequality?).

Comment: Unfortunately, if you just use the fact that $\{ \alpha\}(1-\{\alpha\})$ is bounded, you do not obtain a superior upper bound. Indeed, assuming $q$ is squarefree (as we may), both $\mu(r)^2$ and $\prod_{p\mid q, \, p \nmid r} p(p-2)/(p-1)^2$ are $\asymp 1$, and your idea leads to an upper bound of order $qP^2 \sum_{r \mid q, \, r> 1} r^2/\phi(r)^2$, which is much larger qualitatively than $qPh$ for $q=\prod_{p \le x} p$ with $x \ge \log^2 h$...

Comment: A heuristic for using $\{ \alpha \} (1-\{\alpha\}) \le \alpha$ is that $r^2/\phi(r)^2$ being large is correlated with $r$ being large which is correlated with $\{ h/r \}(1-\{h/r \})$ being of order $h/r$.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'd be happy to accept that as an answer if you'd want to write it up as such.